# Setting GWT CheckBox element id

Tags: html, gwt, checkbox

I am trying to set an element id to GWT checkbox using flowing options, neither any of them assigning id to ckeckbox but wrapped span element.

`DOM.setElementAttribute(testCheckbox.getElement(), "id", "testCheckboxId");` or

```
testCheckbox.getElement().setId("testCheckboxId");
```

compiled HTML looks like:

```
<span id="testCheckboxId" class="gwt-CheckBox">
   <input id="gwt-uid-328" type="checkbox" value="1" tabindex="0" checked="">
   <label for="gwt-uid-328"></label>
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Firs of all you should not change the `id` of an input element for CheckBox. As you can see the `label` element uses this `id` in `for` attribute.

You can get and use the `id` set by GWT:

```
((Element)(testCheckbox.getElement().getFirstChild())).getId()
-- or --
testCheckbox.getElement().getElementsByTagName("input").getItem(0).getId()
```

You can also set the `id` this way, but I don't recommend doing it:

```
((Element)(testCheckbox.getElement().getFirstChild())).setId("xxxxxx");
-- or --
testCheckbox.getElement().getElementsByTagName("input").getItem(0).setId("xxxxxx");
```

---

If you need to change the `id`, you should also change the `for` attribute in `label` element:

```
((LabelElement)(testCheckbox.getElement().getLastChild())).setHtmlFor("xxxxxx");
-- or --
((LabelElement)(testCheckbox.getElement().getElementsByTagName("label").getItem(0))).setHtmlFor("xxxxxx");
```

Comment: I was changing input elements ids for selenium webdriver ui testing.
By the way,
testCheckbox.getElement().getElementsByTagName("input").getItem(0).setId("newIDForCheckbox_");

This bit works as you suggested. Thanks Adam.

Answer (score 0):

You are correctly setting the element id.

Even though it sets the id to the span tag, you'll be able to use it with selenium webdriver. You have to use the following method to locate it.

```
webdriver.findElement(By.xpath, <xpath>)
```

It works fine.

Similarly, for a textbox you can find element using xpath and use "sendKeys()" method to pass values.